# Mongoose Query FindOne with array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So i want to verify if a value is inside the collection. I've managed to do it using *.map*. My code looks like this (the field is nested):

```
  const loopFields = [
    "nested.field1",
    "nested.field2",
    "nested.field3",
    "nested.field4"
  ];

  async function getField() {
    const field = loopFields.map(async (fld, idx) => {
      const result = await Field.findOne({ [fld]: req.body.field });
      if (result) {
        return fld;
      }
    });
    const isFound = await Promise.all(field);
    for (i = 0; i < loopFields.length; i++) {
      if (isFound[i] !== undefined) {
        return true;
      }
    }
  }

const isValid = await getField();

if (!isValid) {
  return res.status(400).send("Field not found");
}
```

The code does work but i'm looking for a way to reffactore it.

Comment: Good question for [Code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

build an `$or` clause dynamically and pass it to the find method like so:

```java
var loopFields = [
    "nested.field1",
    "nested.field2",
    "nested.field3",
    "nested.field4"
];

var fields = loopFields.map(field => {
    var x = {};
    x[field] = req.body.field;
    return x;
})

db.collection.find({ $or: fields });
```

Comment: Worked fine. I've added add an _await_ in _db.collection.find_ so i could use the returned value. Thanks for the help.